# Difference between COM and DCOM?

Tags: visual-c++, com

What is the difference between COM and DCOM ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

DCOM stands for "Distributed COM". That means the client and server can be on different machines communicating across the network, instead of both being on the same machine as in conventional COM.

Comment: +1, Also DCOM allows using a COM DLL on the same machine in a surrogate process with very little effort. Good for 32-bit/64-bit interop.

Answer (score 2):

DCOM=Distributed Component Object Model, you might call it COM via RPC. [DCOM – Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Component_Object_Model)

Comment: Nah, RPC is used in same-machine out-of-process COM as well.

Answer (score 0):

COM stands for **Component Object Model**.
DCOM stands for **Distributed Component Object Model**.

COM is set of component tools which are executed client side.
DCOM is a Distributed component object model runs at the given server.
COM requires installation on the machine from where it is being used.
DCOM requires installation somewhere on the same network.