# Instantiating a COM object remotely gives error 80040154, but works locally

Tags: powershell, com, dcom

I'm trying to instantiate the Shell.Application.1 remotely, but it's giving an error of retrieving COM Class factory. The DLL is registered, and if I log into the remote machine and instantiate it locally (no IP address) it works. PoC code:

```
$com = [activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application.1","192.168.0.11"))
Exception calling "CreateInstance" with "1" argument(s): "Retrieving the COM class factory for remote component with CLSID
{13709620-C279-11CE-A49E-444553540000} from machine 192.168.0.11 failed due to the following error: 80040154 192.168.0.11."
At line:1 char:1
+ $com = [activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.A ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMException
```

On 192.168.0.11:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $com = [activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application.1"))
PS C:\Windows\system32> $com | gm


   TypeName: System.__ComObject#{286e6f1b-7113-4355-9562-96b7e9d64c54}

Name                 MemberType Definition
----                 ---------- ----------
AddToRecent          Method     void AddToRecent (Variant, string)
BrowseForFolder      Method     Folder BrowseForFolder (int, string, int,
```

I already tried re-registering the DLL, I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you instantiate the object from within an `Invoke-Command` block against the remote machine?

Comment: Yes, `Invoke-Command -ComputerName LAB01 -ScriptBlock {$com = [activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application.1"))}`

Answer (score 1):

COM objects cannot be used across a network, but [Distributed COM (DCOM) objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054418/difference-between-com-and-dcom) serve this purpose. I don't believe the [`Shell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell) object is registered as a DCOM object, so you can't directly invoke it remotely as you attempt above. However, as demonstrated in the question comments, you can use PowerShell remoting to instantiate the object on the remote server in a local context.

---

#### [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-5.1)

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName LAB01 {
  $com = [activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application.1"))
}
```

---

#### [`Enter-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession?view=powershell-5.1)

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName LAB01
Enter-PSSession $session
$com = [activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application.1"))
Exit-PSSession
```

> You can actually specify the `-ComputerName` directly on `Enter-PSSession`, however, I like to create a `$session` variable so I can leave and re-enter the same session as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: The object is not a registered DCOM object.